# Structure entry connected to multiple parent entries

Tags: templating, entries, structure, children, parents

Is there a way to connect one structure entry to multiple structure entries?

Like:

[image]

(wonderfully drawn image represents the connection of Food Festival to both structure entries)

Comment: What do you mean by "connect"? You can use a relation field (https://craftcms.com/docs/relations) to relate entries to one another.

Comment: @LukePearce I mean connect as giving it multiple parents (Food festival needs to get 2 parents).

Comment: No you can't. You might be able to use another feature of Craft like categories to produce your outcome though. What are you building that requires the multiple parents? Perhaps update your original question with some details to keep comments to a minimum.