# Can a structure have multiple parents?

Tags: craft3, structure

Can entries of type structure have multiple parents?

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sections-and-entries.html#sections says that they can be hierarchical, but the UX doesn't seem to let me have more than one parent for any given child structure.

Not sure if that is a hard limit or just something misconfigured on my end.

I searched around a bit and saw this answer: [Structure entry connected to multiple parent entries](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16518/structure-entry-connected-to-multiple-parent-entries) which implies that the way to do this is to use relations, not structures, but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is "no, you can't have more than one parent."

Using relationships is probably the best answer. It's unfortunate that Luke didn't expand on his comments and add an official answer (in that other thread), but he was on the right track.

If you create a relationship field, you can relate your entry to as many other entries as you need.